# If $ax^3+bx+c=0$, $bx^3+cx+a=0$, $cx^3+ax+b=0$ have a common root for distinct non-zero $a$, $b$, $c$, then at least one has three real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be distinct nonzero real numbers. If the equations
> $$\begin{align}
> E_1: ax^3+bx+c=0 \\
> E_2: bx^3+cx+a=0 \\
> E_3: cx^3+ax+b=0
> \end{align}$$
> have a common root, prove that at least one of these equations has three real roots (not necessarily distinct).

This question was a math olympiad problem.Below was my attempt but I've got confused:

I know that the discriminant of the equation $x^3+Ax+B=0$ is given by $-4A^3-27B^2$, so it suffices to prove that the discriminant of at one least of the equations is non-negative.

It's easy to prove that the common root $r$ must be real. Now assume on the contrary that all three equations had a pair of complex conjugate roots. Let $\alpha, \bar{\alpha}, \beta, \bar{\beta}, \gamma, \bar{\gamma}$ be the complex conjugate roots of $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ respectively.

Then by viete theorem, we have $$\alpha \bar{\alpha} r=|\alpha|^2r=\frac{-c}{a},$$
$$|\beta|^2r=\frac{-a}{b},$$
$$|\gamma|^2r=\frac{-b}{c}.$$
Multiplying the three equations gives $$|\alpha \beta \gamma|^2r^3=-1.$$
Hence $r<0.$ Hence $-c/a<0$ or $c/a>0.$ Similarly $a/b>0$ and $b/c>0.$ This implies that $a,b,c$ all all positive or or negative.

By symmetry, we can assume $a>b>c>0$, but then none of the discriminant could be non-negative. So what's wrong with the argument and how can I complete the proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "none of the discriminant could be non-negative" is contradict to your assumption "$\alpha, \bar{\alpha}, \beta, \bar{\beta}, \gamma, \bar{\gamma}$be the complex conjugate roots of $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ respectively".

Comment: Your proof is almost done!

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont get it, we have $a>b>c>0$, hence the discriminant of $E_1$ is $-4(b/3)^3-27(c/a)^2$ must be negative. Similarly for $E_2$ and $E_3$, pleas helps... thanks.

Comment: All your reasoning is correct but the definition of the discriminant is a bit problematic: it should be [$A^3/27+B^2/4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method)

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be the common root, then

$$(a+b+c)(r^3+r+1)=0 \tag{$E_1+E_2+E_3$}$$

**Case I**:

> If $r^3+r+1=0$, then $(ar^3+br+c)-a(r^3+r+1)=0$
>
> $$\implies (a-b)r=(c-a)$$
>
> By symmetry, $$r=\frac{c-a}{a-b}=\frac{a-b}{b-c}=\frac{b-c}{c-a}$$
>
> $$c=\frac{a+b \pm i(a-b)\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
>
> Or equivalently,
>
> $$r=\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
>
> that contradicts with $r^3+r+1=0$.

**Case II**:

> If $a+b+c=0$, then $r=1$.
>
> For $x\neq 1$,
>
> $$\frac{ax^3+bx+c}{x-1}=ax^2+ax-c=0$$
>
> $$\Delta_{1}=a^2+4ac$$
>
> Similarly,
>
> $$\Delta_{2}=b^2+4ba$$
>
> $$\Delta_{3}=c^2+4cb$$
>
> Since $a+b+c=0$, **either two** of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are of equal sign.
>
> That is **either one** of $ab$, $bc$ and $ca$ is positive.
>
> **At least one** of the $\Delta_{1}$, $\Delta_{2}$ and $\Delta_{3}$ is positive.

---

**Further points to be noticed**

For $r \ne 1$ and $a+b+c=0$,

$$\frac{r^3-1}{r-1}=-\frac{b}{a}=-\frac{c}{b}=-\frac{a}{c} \implies a=b\omega=c\omega^2 \land \omega^3=1$$

which does not give **distinct, non-zero and real** values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Also considering the matrix equation:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  b & c & a \\
  c & a & b
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  r^3 \\  r \\  1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\  0 \\  0
\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=a+b+c$ and
$\lambda_{2,3}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+(a-b)^2}{2}}$.

For the matrix is singular,

$$\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3=0$$

The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1=a+b+c$ is
$$\vec{v_1}=(1,1,1) \implies r^3=r=1$$

For $a=b=c$, $$\lambda_{2,3}=0 \implies r^3+r+1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all three have only one solution.

Then $3ax^2+b$ is always positive or negative i.e. $ab<0$. The same way we get $ac<0$ and $bc<0$. Impossible.